# How to start Gulmohar bonsai from seeds?

Tags: germination, bonsai, seed-saving

I have so many Gulmohar around. How can I use Gulmohar fruit/flower to start my own Gulmohar bonsai.

Answer (score 1):

If you have so many Gulmohar  around, I wouldn't start with seeds or cuttings, but I would dig out a small tree (sapling of ~2-3 year old). Depending on how big you would like to make your bonsai, you can take a sapling that has a firm stem already, let's say a stem of 2-3 cm (1 inch) in diameter.

Then, start trimming the plant into your favorite form and also trim the roots, before putting it in a bonsai pot.

There are instructions on internet of how to do this with other species, for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4_JLdRVoqA).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a cutting might be a better option. If you start from a cutting you have a season or two head start. This is a lot when growing a bonsai as it will look mature faster.

**The quick version**

Cuttings can be taken from the previous seasons growth. This means not the new green shoots but the little bit firmer thin branches that have darker bark. Take multiple cuttings to have a higher chance of success.

Basically you cut pieces af about 10-15 cm and stick them half way into a pot. It is important that the direction in which they where growing is the part above ground.

- Keep the ground moist but not wet.
- Do not put in direct sunlight.
- Covering the pot with a plastic bottle or anything that keeps it humid is a good idea

Transplant once they have a good amount of leaves and show signs of trunk growth.

Growing from cuttings is an art in and of itself. There is a lot to be read about it online and lots of different methods. You can even use rooting hormones to help it root better and faster. I suggest looking around and finding one that fits you.

**Edit**

Angelo Eliades over at Deep Green Permaculture does a good job of illustrating the process in [this](https://deepgreenpermaculture.com/diy-instructions/propagating-hardwood-cuttings/) article.

**Note**

The bonsai part only comes once you have the cuttings successfully growing. There is no special way to start when wanting to grow a bonsai. At first they will just be saplings which then over the years turn into bonsai trees as you prune them to keep them small.

Comment: Few questions:`1.` `little bit firmer thin branches that have darker bark` can you  show an example?I dont have good experience of growing anything cutting/seeds. `2. ` I have a bisleri bottle I cut a nice branch as suggested, put it in bottle w/o any mud(potting mix), but wrap it nicely the lower part with paper towel socked in aspirin water and wait for new leaves. Will this be good idea? If Yes should I put this air tight bottle in direct sunlight? If roots grow will they be strong enough to break out of paper towel?

Comment: 1. I updated the answer with a link to a good illustrated article on growing cuttings.

2. Yes the roots will grow through paper towel but I have never tried this technique myself. What I have done that has worked for me is to put the cutting in potting soil then cut the bottle in half and put it over the cutting to make a sort of green house.

Comment: That sounds beautiful "Greenhouse" can you share pic? `Secondly`, should I put that greenhouse in direct sunlight??

Comment: I would never put the cuttings in direct sunlight until you are completely sure they have grown roots. I would also suggest leaving the one you aready made, as it might grow. You can try a second cutting with soil. Growing cutting can take a little experimentation and some trial and error. Dont get discouraged if most of them dont grow, you get better at it and in time you learn the trick of the trade.

Comment: You mean to say keep it in `air tight` bottle until it shows new leaves and in indirect sunlight, like under a porch, near window??

Comment: Yes, keep it in there until it grows roots that are a few cm long, then it is ready to be planted. Whether air tight or with a few holes/cap off is better I dont know.

This is a good example of bottle 'greenhouses'.
https://containergardening.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/recycle-a-plastic-bottle-into-a-very-simple-mini-greenhouse-for-seedling-growth-willem-van-cotthem-tine-dau/